# JSF2 ManagedBeans Lifecycle

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a basic question about JSF and their ManagedBeans. Imagine we have set a ManagedBean that only contains data for and from my view:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dataBean")
@SessionScoped
public class DataBean {
```

Next here is my controller with a dependency injection to connect controller with model:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Controller {
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{dataBean}")
  private DataBean dataBean;
```

---

Now let's think about several managedBeans in one controller: Is it possible to inject another ManagedBean to the controller like:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{dataBean}")
private DataBean dataBean;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{dataBean}")
private DataBean dataBean2;
```

And if so, how does JSF know what bean belongs to what .xhtml page?

---

I am very confused at the moment :-/ Because there is something wrong with my code... But first I should understand it clearly

Cheers...

### Addition:

Let's say I want to access the same managedBean (sessionScoped) out of two controllers. Can I easy say:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Controller {
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{dataBean}")
  private DataBean dataBean;
...
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Controller2 {
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{dataBean}")
  private DataBean dataBean;
```

And I have the same instance of DataBean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{dataBean}")
private DataBean dataBean;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{dataBean}")
private DataBean dataBean2;
```

Will inject the same instance in `dataBean` and `dataBean2`. There is only one `#{dataBean}`.

**Addition** (answer for question Addition :) )

Yes, if `dataBean` is `@SessionScoped`, in both controllers you get the same `DataBean`. There is only one in current session.

Comment: all right: that's why i should use a controller for any view... thank's